# How to use MatSort with table of type Object[]

Tags: angular

I wanted to use SortHeader in table of type Object, I don't want to change the type of my table to MatTableDataSource, Any Help ?

This is my datasource

```
elements: Object[] = []
```

what should I do in my ngOnInit() ?
this doesn't work

```
this.elements.sort = this.sort;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to listen to the `matSortChange` event on your table.

```html
<table #myTable mat-table [dataSource]="sortedData" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
```

Implement custom sorting logic and provide the sorted data when `matSortChange` triggers.

```ts
@ViewChild('myTable') table: MatTable<Object>;

data: Object[] = [
    { name: 'Frozen yogurt', calories: 159, fat: 6, carbs: 24, protein: 4 },
    { name: 'Ice cream sandwich', calories: 237, fat: 9, carbs: 37, protein: 4 },
    { name: 'Eclair', calories: 262, fat: 16, carbs: 24, protein: 6 },
    { name: 'Cupcake', calories: 305, fat: 4, carbs: 67, protein: 4 },
    { name: 'Gingerbread', calories: 356, fat: 16, carbs: 49, protein: 4 },
];

sortedData: Object[];

constructor() {
    this.sortedData = this.data.slice();
}

sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.data.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }

    this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a['name'], b['name'], isAsc);
        case 'calories': return compare(a['calories'], b['calories'], isAsc);
        case 'fat': return compare(a['fat'], b['fat'], isAsc);
        case 'carbs': return compare(a['carbs'], b['carbs'], isAsc);
        case 'protein': return compare(a['protein'], b['protein'], isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
}

function compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
    return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

If you don't supply a new sorted array as `dataSource` on sort events but instead do the sort in place (in the existing dataSource array), you additionally have to call `this.table.renderRows()` after the sort as the table will not automatically check the array for changes.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwkods